# Import Jupyter notebook as module, but allow inspect

Tags: python, import, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a project where I'm importing a notebook as a module into another module.
I use the [example](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/5.x/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb) on the IPython GH and it works fine.

However, now I'm trying to add a feature for which I need to access the source code (`inspect.getsourcelines()`) of a function/class-method.
The feature works when I execute it inside one notebook.
However, as soon as I import the function as a module, inspect cannot read the sources anymore.

This is because the code is executed via `exec(code, mod.__dict__)` which, as expected and Python default, will not allow the sources to be read.

I searched for a while but didn't find a conclusive answer yet, so here my questions:

1. Why is in the example the source code executed with `exec`? (My suspicion: because the code is beforehand transformed)
        EDIT: Why is [`run_cell`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8d399b98d3ed5c765835594100c4d36fb2f739dc/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2592) not used in the example?
2. In general, what happens when I execute a Jupyter cell? Does the code get transformed there? EDIT: I assume it's [`run_cell`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8d399b98d3ed5c765835594100c4d36fb2f739dc/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2592), am I right?
3. Is it possible to modify the module-import-example to use the standard "execute-cell" command and allow using `inspect` to look at the sources?

Answer (score 0):

So I still haven't found a fully acceptable solution.

For anybody interested: As a workaround I'm using the `%run filename` command which imports everything into the local notebook (and also prints all outputs that it executes [1])

The problem: everything is 'local' and not in a submodule. That means any variables defined in the imported notebook are accessible and overwrite existing ones. This can become a bit annoying. (But right now I'm at least happy that it works somewhat).

[1] `%%capture` blocks the output and makes it at least clean.